# Selenium - Java: How to get absolute path to the file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, automated-tests, absolute-path

I created the method where I get an absolute path but when I debug I get an incorrect path to the file which should be uploaded.

So, the method where I get absolute path:

```
public String getFilePathByFormat(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Then I use this method in the general low-level method for uploading:

```
public void uploadFile(WebElement webElement, String filePath){
        try {
            webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, SECONDS);
            webElement.sendKeys(getFilePathByFormat(filePath));
        }catch (Exception e){
            printErrorAndStopTest();
        }
    }
```

And when I debug and evaluate incorrect path gets:
E:\acceptance-tests\src\test\resources, BUT after disk name, one more folder should be - where the project located.

What's wrong and why getAbsolutePath doesn't build the correct path?
Thanks

Comment: It might be helpful to actually post the value of filePath...

Comment: filePath value I indicate as a String in page class:

public void uploadNeededAttachmentAndSetType() {
     
        uploadFile("/acceptance-tests/src/test/resources/test4.pdf");
      
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of file path in file system.

1) **An absolute path always starts from root element** and contains complete directory list required to locate the file. For example, '/Users/username/filename.txt' on Unix systems or 'C:\Users\username\filename.txt' on Windows systems.

A relative path does not have any directory listing and needs to be combined with another path in order to access a file. For example, username/filename.txt is a relative path; Note that it does not have any forward or backward slashes at the beginning.

**getAbsolutePath()** returns the absolute path of a file and works like below.

1. File object is created with absolute pathname - This method simply returns the pathname provided to create the file. **And in case of Windows System, drive name is appended at beginning by default if it is not present in absolute path name given**.
2. File object is created using relative path - Here relative path name is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory.

In this case, absolute path '/acceptance-tests/src/test/resources/test4.pdf' is passed; As mentioned for windows system, drive details are prefixed with given path and returned as absolute path.

To make it work, you can pass the relative path of file 'src/test/resources/test4.pdf' or just pass the file name 'test4.pdf'.

Comment: Thanks for description. I have tried with a relative path or just leave file name but it does not work. 
Also, I have tried to use dots: `./acceptance-tests/src/test/resources/test4.pdf` but it duplicates the folder before which the dot is set: `E:/AutomationsTests/acceptance-tests/./acceptance-tests/src/test/resources/test4.pdf` - the result of evaluation during debugging.  */acceptance-tests* folder duplicates in the path

Comment: If I am correct 'acceptance-tests'  is your project folder name. Please remove that name as well as dot from your input file path. Your input should be 'src/test/resources/test4.pdf'

Comment: When I remove the project folder name and dot the test fails. When I debugging and evaluate `getFilePathByFormat(filePath)` the result is E:/src/test/resources/test4.pdf what is incorrect

Comment: The problem was in "/" before "src". Removed it and tests are run.
Thanks